# What does it mean for a marginal CDF (induced from a prob. measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$) to have an "atom"?

Tags: probability-theory

For example, suppose we have some probability measure $μ$ on the set $\{q\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i\leq 2\}$

Define the marginal CDF over $x_i$ to be
$$
F^i(x_i)=\int_{x_j}\int_{y_i\leq x_i}d\mu
$$

What does it mean for $F^i$ to have an atom at $x_i=z_i$, for some $z_i$?

Does it mean that the probability "jumps there" (i.e. the pdf has an atom?)

But I am confused because $F^i$ is derived from $μ$, which is defined on two dimensions. So does an atom at $z_i$ mean that a **point** in $\{q\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i\leq 2\}$ has positive probability, or does it mean that a **line** in that set has positive probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say "the marginal distribution has an atom" you are talking about "the marginal distribution." Whether a distribution has an atom or not doesn't make any reference to where the distribution comes from (i.e. whether it's a marginal distribution of some higher-dimensional distribution).

So, if we have some measure on some disk and we are talking about the marginal distribution of one of the coordinates (let's call it $X$), the CDF of this is just $F_X(x) = P(X\le x)$ as usual. An atom is a point $x$ such that $P(X=x)>0$ (so, yes, the CDF jumps there... the marginal CDF, that is).

$X=x$ represents a line in the original two-dimensional space, so in terms of this space, $P(X=x)>0$ means that a line has a positive probability. But in the one-dimensional projection $X$ lives on, it means a point has positive probability.